# bring to front not working winform c# my code

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

i have telerik panel i want show to form in front but form not show bringtofront not working. i don't know why please check below image and code, i am clicking product button but product form show back side ;(

```
frmProductList objForm = new frmProductList();
                pndocmain.DockControl(objForm, DockPosition.Fill, DockType.Document);
                objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                objForm.TopMost = true;              
                objForm.BringToFront();

               objForm.Show();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first thing, that I would try is show the form with owner. But I really don’t know, why you haven’t that in front even though you have TopMost as true.

```
frmProductList objForm = new frmProductList();
            pndocmain.DockControl(objForm, DockPosition.Fill, DockType.Document);
            objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            //objForm.TopMost = true;              
            //objForm.BringToFront();

           objForm.Show(this);
```